# How to set not to automatically merge tsfile in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: merge, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I found that Apache IoTDB will automatically merge tsfile to control the number and size of tsfile. Since I am not sure if I can find the original data if the original tsfile is joined, I am curious that if IoTDB can set not to automatically merge tsfile? If this process can be stopped, how should I do that? Or is there any way for me to easily find the tsfile for certain time series if it is merged?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please